# showing updated data in the table dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I do have a form and table.I am binding the form through the table and I am able to do that but my concern is I want to update any of the field from the form but it is not showing in the table instantly.It is showing in the table but after refreshing the page.But I want that is must be dynamic.
the code for the table and the binding the form is as follows:

```
    <form class="form  form-horizontal" id="serviceactivityForm" data-bind="foreach:items" action="<?php echo $BASE;?>projects/service_activities"  method="post">
                <div class="span3">
                        <input type="hidden" id="data_actid" name="actid" data-bind="value: actid" />
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label labellocation">Subject</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="inputmargin" data-bind='value: subject' title="Please Enter Subject" required="" style="width:150px"/></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label labellocation">Location</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="location"  name="location" data-bind='value: location' class="inputmargin" style="width:150px"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
<form class="form" action="<?php echo $BASE;?>projects/service_activities">
        <div class="datagrid span4">  
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered selectable " style="width:450px;" id="service_activitiesTable">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Subject</th>
                                        <th>Location</th>
                                        <th>Assigned</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: items" >
                            <tr data-bind="value:actid" id="service_activity">
                            <td data-bind="text:subject"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text:location"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text:techname"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </form> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#service_activity").live('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: root + "projects/service_activities?json",
                    data: { id: $(this).val() },
                    success: function (o) {
                        ko.applyBindings(new DynamicModel(o.service_activity), document.getElementById("serviceactivityForm"));

                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            });
         });
    </script>
```

so is there any way to do this..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184199/how-to-update-an-array-table-dynamically-with-ajax-and-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show your view model and inital binding code?

At a guess, it's because you are creating a new viewmodel when you save, and are applying the binding using that. You should be bound to an items property that is an observable array, and you want to be adding to it with the updated values, not over-writing it.